# Finding area of section of a circle

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

So my calculus teacher made a test in which she made a mistake. 
Their was a piecewise function she graphed and we were supposed to do a definite integral on. 
Part of this function was a semicircle with a radius of $2$ and a center at the origin. 
Now if I had to calculate the integral from $0$ to $2$ that would be easy! It's just $\pi$. Or if I had to do $0$ to $-2$ that would be easy as well it is just $-\pi$.

However she misspelled the question...  AND as a result we had to calculate the integral from $1$ to $2$... Which really confused me.

While she meant to write "$0$ to $2$" I am still curious..... How would one calculate the area of a section of the semicircle?

Comment: You can find the problem re-phrased (and an answer given) here: https://www.exeter.edu/documents/Math4All.pdf on page 66 (problems 1,2,3.) You actually don't really need to use calculus methods at all!

Answer (score 1):

Well, the function of a semicircle above the $x$-axis is simply this:

$$y=\sqrt{ r^2 - x^2 }$$

where $r$ is the radius of the circle (in your case, it is $2$).
You would then find the definite integral from $1$ to $2$ of that function.

Answer (score 1):

Lets first look at this using classical geometry and a little trig.

The area area in question is the area of a section of the circle (the pie slice including the origin) less the area of a triangle.

The section of a cirlce: $A = \frac {1}{2} r^2 \theta$.
The triangle: $A = \frac{1}{2} bh$

$b = r\cos\theta, h=r\sin \theta$

$A = \frac{1}{2} r^2 (\theta - \sin \theta cos \theta)$
and in this case $r=2$ and $\theta = \pi/3$

Using calculus:

$x^2 + y^2 = 4$

$\int_1^2 (4-x^2)^{1/2} dx$

$x = 2 \cos \theta$
$dx = -2 \sin \theta \, d\theta$

limits of integration:
$2 \cos \theta = 1; \theta = \pi/3$

$2 \cos \theta = 2; \theta = 0$

$\int_{\pi/3}^{0} (4-4\cos^2\theta)^{1/2} (-2\sin\theta \, d\theta)$

$\int_{0}^{\pi/3} 4 sin^2 \theta \, d\theta$

Half angle indentity:
$2 sin^2\theta = 1 - \cos\,2\theta$

$\int_{0}^{\pi/3} 2(1- \cos\,2\theta) \, d\theta$

$2(\theta - \frac{1}{2} \sin\,2\theta) |_0^{\pi/3}$

$2(\theta -  \sin\theta\cos\theta) |_0^{\pi/3}$

$2(\pi/3 -  \frac{\sqrt 3}{4})$